# Why does my webpage not return an updated list after adding objects? Using Flask

Tags: python, html, css, server

This is my python code. Any idea what is wrong/missing? I am using Flask to host a local web server. I am not experienced in HTML or CSS, so I am using templates provided by my course. I am able to successfully run the program, but if I add a check or deposit via the webpage, the webpage that is supposed to display all transactions is blank, despite appending the list earlier.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

register_items = []
balance = 0.0


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("checkbook-form.html")


@app.route('/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def compute():
    global balance
    # For a POST request to /transaction, request.form is a dictionary that contains the posted
    # form data. It should have values for 'number', 'date', 'description', and 'amount'.
    # Convert 'amount' to float and add it to the balance.
    # Create a dictionary with the values for 'number', 'date',
    # 'description', 'amount', and balance, and append the dictionary to the
    # register_items list so the user can see the new entry in the results.
    number = request.form["number"]
    date = request.form["date"]
    description = request.form["description"]
    amount = float(request.form["amount"])
    balance = balance + amount
    dictionary = {1: number, 2: date, 3: description, 4: amount, 5: balance}
    register_items.append(dictionary)

    # Render the output page. Send the register_items list to the page to show to the user:
    return render_template("checkbook-result.html", content=register_items)


# hosted on localhost, which is http://localhost:8080/
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I have tried to figure this our myself with no success. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[Check/Deposits Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHguP.jpg)
[Transactions Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IojA1.jpg)

Comment: share your html file too

Comment: just check your jinja template, see how you are accessing data there

Comment: here's the [html](https://pastebin.com/EJC3csQm)

Answer (score 0):

can you also share the checkbook-result.html.
because the displaying or outputting of the data happened on the template
thanks

Comment: Here's the [html](https://pastebin.com/EJC3csQm)